# NodeJs : bulk insert into SQL Server one-to-many

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I want to using nodejs mssql package to bulk insert data with below json:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Tom",
        "registerDate": "2021-10-10 00:00:00",
        "gender": 0,
        "consumeRecord":[
            {
                "date": "2021-10-11 00:00:00",
                "price": 102.5
            },
            {
                "date": "2021-10-12 00:00:00",
                "price": 200
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Mary",
        "registerDate": "2021-06-10 00:00:00",
        "gender": 1,
        "consumeRecord":[
            {
                "date": "2021-07-11 00:00:00",
                "price": 702.5
            },
            {
                "date": "2021-12-12 00:00:00",
                "price": 98.2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am try to mssql bulk insert for the member record with multiple consume data?

Is there anything can insert one to many with bulk insert like below.
because it seems need to insert the member table and get the id (primary key) first. Then using the id (primary key) for the consume table relation data

```
const sql = require('mssql')

// member table
const membertable = new sql.Table('Member')
table.columns.add('name', sql.Int, {nullable: false})
table.columns.add('registerDate', sql.VarChar(50), {nullable: false})
table.columns.add('gender', sql.VarChar(50), {nullable: false})

// consume record table
const consumeTable = new sql.Table('ConsumeRecord')
table.columns.add('MemberId', sql.Int, {nullable: false})
table.columns.add('Date', sql.VarChar(50), {nullable: false})
table.columns.add('price', sql.Money, {nullable: false})

// insert into member table
jsonList.forEach(data => {

    table.rows.add(data.name)
    table.rows.add(data.registerDate)
    table.rows.add(data.gender)

    consumeTable.rows.add(data.memberId) // <---- should insert member table id
    consumeTable.rows.add(data.consumeRecord.data)
    consumeTable.rows.add(data.consumeRecord.price)

    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.bulk(consumeTable , (err, result) => {

    })

})


const request = new sql.Request()
request.bulk(membertable , (err, result) => {

})
```

Expected Record:
Member Table

| id (auto increment) | name | registerDate | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | 2021-10-10 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 2 | Mary | 2021-06-10 00:00:00 | 1 |

Consume Record Table

| id | MemberId | Date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-10-10 00:00:00 | 102.5 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-10-12 00:00:00 | 200 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-07-11 00:00:00 | 702.5 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 98.2 |

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to upload the whole thing in batch to SQL Server, and ensure that it inserts the correct foreign key.

You have two options

- Option 1

  - Upload the main table as a Table Valued Parameter or JSON blob
  - Insert with `OUTPUT` clause to select the inserted IDs back to the client
  - Correlate those IDs back to the child table data
  - Bulk Insert that as well
- Option 2 is a bit easier: do the whole thing in SQL

  - Upload everything as one big JSON blob
  - Insert main table with `OUTPUT` clause into table variable
  - Insert child table, joining the IDs from the table variable

```sql
CREATE TABLE Member(
  Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(50),
  registerDate datetime NOT NULL,
  gender tinyint NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE ConsumeRecord(
  MemberId Int NOT NULL REFERENCES Member (Id),
  Date datetime not null,
  price decimal(9,2)
);
```

Note the more sensible datatypes of the columns

```sql
DECLARE @ids TABLE (jsonIndex nvarchar(5) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 not null, memberId int not null);

WITH Source AS (
    SELECT
      j1.[key],
      j2.*
    FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value)
      WITH (
        name varchar(50),
        registerDate datetime,
        gender tinyint
      ) j2
)
MERGE Member m
USING Source s
  ON 1=0 -- never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (name, registerDate, gender)
  VALUES (s.name, s.registerDate, s.gender)
OUTPUT s.[key], inserted.ID
  INTO @ids(jsonIndex, memberId);
  
INSERT ConsumeRecord (MemberId, Date, price)
SELECT
  i.memberId,
  j2.date,
  j2.price
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value, '$.consumeRecord')
  WITH (
    date datetime,
    price decimal(9,2)
  ) j2
JOIN @ids i ON i.jsonIndex = j1.[key];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7ee296ce5fd44ce10caf5718171e6d7)

Unfortunately, `INSERT` only allows you to `OUTPUT` from the `inserted` table, not from any non-inserted columns. So we need to hack it with a weird `MERGE`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change database schema and add `uniqueidentifier` column, it would simplify things a lot, as you can generate `GUID`s at the client side before directly inserting them to the database.

### `uniqueidentifier` column as a non PK column

This columns is used as a "temporary" key to help client applications retrieve `identity` values of the inserted records.

In your case once you inserted data into the first table, you can run a query to get PKs based on the `uniqueidentifier` and populate FK columns of the second table.

### `uniqueidentifier` column as a PK column

Use `uniqueidentifier` types column as PK / FKs in your database. You can easily import data hierarchies without any voodoo magic to handle `identity` values.